# WSS server locking domain admin account

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user-accounts, domain

One of our domain admin accounts continues to be locked out on the hour every hour by our Sharepoint 2010 server.  I have looked in the list of managed accounts and service accounts and this particular account doesn't appear.  It's not cached in Windows on this server either.  This account is also not used to RDP or otherwise log into this Sharepoint server.

How can I figure out what process is causing this account to lock out?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a couple of additional things which might run under the locked account:

- Processes in TaskManager
- ApplicationPools in IIS
- Windows-Services running in services.msc
- Recurring task in TaskScheduler

If you know the application, we can help you how to get rid of it.

Comment: No processes running as this user account while not logged in as that user.  Checked the Application Pools, none list an identity of this user account.  No services are set to run under this user account, and no tasks in the Task Scheduler run under this account either... Any other ideas?